# Fit an exponential function to time-series data

Tags: python-3.x, optimization, time-series, curve-fitting, estimation

I've to fit the following exponential function to a time-series data ([data](https://github.com/DeepaMahm/misc/blob/master/sample.txt)).

```
$C(t)$ = $C_{\infty} (1-\exp(-\frac{t}{\tau}))$
```

I want to compute the time scale `$\tau$` at which `C(t)` reaches `$C_{\infty}$`. I would like to ask for suggestions on how `$\tau$` can be computed. I found an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33186740/fitting-exponential-function-through-two-data-points-with-scipy-curve-fit) that use curve fitting. But I am not sure how to use `curve_fit` library in `scipy` to set up the problem described above.

Comment: Sorry I cannot import your data. Could you post it on another format. Could the data be separated into two distinct files ?

Comment: @JJacquelin Thanks so much for the response. Please find the new files here : [time](https://github.com/DeepaMahm/misc/blob/master/time.txt) and [values](https://github.com/DeepaMahm/misc/blob/master/data.txt). I've updated it as two separate text files. Kindly let me know if you would like to access in some other format .

Answer (score 1):

One cannot expect a good fitting along the whole curve with the function that you choose.

This is because especially at t=0 this function returns C=0 while the data value is C=2.5 .This is very far considering the order of magnitude.

Nevertheless on can try to fit this function for a rough result. A non-linear regression calculus is necessary : this is the usual approach using available softwares. This is the recommended method in context of academic exercices.

Alternatively and more simply, a linear regression can be used thanks to a non-conventional method explained in https://fr.scribd.com/doc/14674814/Regressions-et-equations-integrales .

The result is shown below.

[image]

For a better fitting one have to take account of the almost constant value of data in the neighborhood of t=0. Choosing a function made of two logistic functions would be recommended. But the calculus is more complicated.

**IN ADDITION, AFTER THE OP CHANGES THE DATA :**

The change of data makes out of date the above answer.

In fact artificially changing the origin of the y-scale so that y=0 at t=0 changes nothing. The slope at t=0 of the chosen fonction is far to be nul, while the slope of the data curve is almost 0. This remains incompatible.

Definitively the chosen function y=C*(1-exp(-t/tau)) cannot fit correctly the data (the preceeding data or the new data as well).

[image]

As already pointed out, for a better fitting one have to take account of the almost constant value of data in the neighborhood of t=0. Choosing a function made of two logistic functions would be recommended. But the calculus is more complicated.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. I've some updates now and the new data value is 0 at t=0. Please find the updated data [here](https://github.com/DeepaMahm/misc/blob/master/data.txt).  Could you explain how $\tau$ can be estimated for the updated dataset?

Comment: See my comment in addition to the main answer.